# Rails 5, Ajax, jQuery - increase number when button clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

If user clicks "Add to Cart" button, I need to increase the number by one in my navbar div, to show how many products are in his cart.

So, my button has `remote: true` set

And navbar has a div with id **count**.

Function I use to increase number:

```
$('#count').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
```

But if I reload page that value disappears. How I can make that value stay there until some action, like 'checkout'?

Or maybe there is a better way for this?

Comment: Well, you need to save that value somewhere, like in DB or in a cookie.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a model method or helper method for the user for finding the count of the active cart items. so that it provides the accurate value too.

For example:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :cart_items
 def active_cart_items
   return self.cart_items.group_by(&:product_id).count #.where(status:active)  (optional)
 end
end
```

create `ur_action.js.erb` under `ur_controller` in that set items in cart counter

```
$('#count').html("<%=@user.active_cart_items%>")
```

Comment: I add your comment as an answer since u showed the syntax how to input Ruby part into the JS. That I didint knew (yes, now it looks simple...). But I will still have to work on this, since I am using this method to add new cart_item: `def add_product(product)
current_item = cart_items.find_by(product_id: product.id) if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
else
current_item = cart_items.build(product_id: product.id) end
  current_item
end`

Comment: so if user adds multiple same cart_items they are not being multiplied

Comment: ah, some fresh air and rails console made my day. Answer is simple as that: @cart.cart_items.map { |i| i[:quantity] }.sum

Answer (score 0):

> You need to store the cart items to the database. On click of button ,
>   an ajax(`remote: true`)  will be fired which will update the cart
>   count in the database & will return the corresponding js.erb file
>   which will update the count in the navbar